ADF - How to set item from for each loop into copy data
I have below url set as baseurl in http linked service:
https://app.zipcodebase.com/api/v1/country/province?apikey=997db720-a95e-dd921aaa6fad&country=

I have created below datasets and set relative url as item() to get value from for eachloop:

Also I have create pipeline parameter and set it to items inside the foreach loop:


but when I debug the pipeline it's getting failed and giving below error:

ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http
request failed with client error, status code 404 NotFound, please
check your activity settings. If you configured a baseUrl that
includes path, please make sure it ends with '/'. Request URL:
https://app.zipcodebase.com/api/v1/country/item().,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The
remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.,Source=System,'

I think there is an issue with Relative URL, can you please help me resolve issue?

Data sets are not directly connected to the pipeline run, so you have hardcoded "item()" into your path rather than a reference to the runtime data.
Instead, use a parameter in your data set:

Then set the value of your relative URL to the parameter:

In the pipeline, pass item() as the dataset parameter value:


Thanks and appreciated Joel for the answer. I also found a link from Microsoft community https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/647604/datafactory-multi-relative-url-expressions
